# Laravel5 Ubuntu only working when myvirtualdomain/index.php/subsites

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed LAMP, Composer and I installed Laravel. I created virtual domain (laravel.dev) and it works, but only when I'm using for simple laravel.dev/index.php/auth/login. When I use laravel.dev/css I have laravel/public/css folder. I have default .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    AllowOverride All

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my *.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I fix it?
My main page:
http://i.imgur.com/AxQjV9q.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fall this problem.I solved it using apache mod rewrite enable.For that follow this
http://www.kingpabel.com/apache-mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your virtualhost doesn't allow overriding the rewriting settings in the .htaccess of your project.

You should add the following lines to your .conf file, in the virtualhost :

```
<Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Which would result in the following file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```